# Ubuntu freezes on opening android studio and browser

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, bug-reporting, android-studio, android-sdk

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I run both android studio and chrome or any other browser at the same time, the system freezes. Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysReq</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> isn't working. Is there anyway this can be solved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally, if you need to report a bug, do it at [Launchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). In addition, what hardware are you running (CPU+RAM, but I doubt this has much to do with your issue)?

Comment: Are you sure you have enough RAM GigaBytes and CPU power? Android Studio is particularly demanding in terms of resources, so you may want to check that first. E.g, to see how much RAM you have, type: `free -h | awk '/Mem:/{print $2}'`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'm new to ubuntu, so I didn't know where to start.  I'll use launchpad from hereon. I've 1TB HD (200GB for system) and 3GB of ram, with Intel Core i3. Irrecoverable Freezing issue got solved by adding swap space(of 3GB). Freezing occurs nonetheless. It was fine in windows though. On running free -h | awk '/Mem:/{print $2}' , i got a value of 2.7G.